# Restrict EventHandler In Specific Columns Of Datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

I have tried to restrict Following EventHandler In specific Columns of Datagridview but fail to do so.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,     
DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {

 if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex==0) 
        {
            if (e.Control is TextBox) 
            {
                TextBox dgvEditBox  = e.Control as TextBox;
                dgvEditBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dgvEditBox_TextChanged);

            }

        }


    }



  private void dgvEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Extract the textbox control
        TextBox dgvEditBox = (TextBox)sender;
      //  TextBox dgvEditBox = new TextBox();

        //Insert the appropriate string
        if (dgvEditBox.Text.Length == 1)
        {
            if (dgvEditBox.Text == "B" || dgvEditBox.Text == "b")
            {
                dgvEditBox.Text = "Ball";
            }
        }    
    }
```

The above code suggested that I am trying to put **“Ball”** text into **datagridview1’s “0”** column but it’s

affect others columns like **if I press “b” or “B” on columns 1 than it’s also return “Ball” on columns 1.**

Which I don’t want. **Is It possible to restrict it upto columns”O” only as per above way?.**

Comment: try to reach columnIndex, and restrict it in eventHandler like if(columnIndex == 0) //Dont Do..

Comment: @Serkan Hekimoglu, Sorry I don't get you. your mean in dgvEditBox_textchange" EventHandler?. How ?. can You explain in detail please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to function `dgvEditBox_TextChanged` at the last line outside the `if (dgvEditBox.Text.Length == 1)` block;

```
dgvEditBox.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(dgvEditBox_TextChanged);
```

Comment: @HPT, Yes It is the brilliant Idea. To revoke the access of EventHandler. Your Wel-Come.